# How to use select with a variable

Tags: sql, where-in

To simplify I have a table and I just want to make a select with the data at blue, is  tricky for me because I must use the `where textanswer='dimibilli d2'` but I will only get the records 5, 7, 10, 12 but I want to get the 6, 8, 9 to

How can I do this?

[image: Table]

Comment: what database you are using, SQL is just a query language

Comment: _"but i want to get the 6, 8, 9 to"_ Why? Because their `TextAnswer` is blank? Or what? Please explain why you want the result you want. Anyway, I don't see any variable here...

Comment: @underscore_d; because they have the same transdocnumber.  Some SO posts are like puzzles :D

Comment: @underscore_d I guess OP also wants to include empty string rows aswel in where clause

Comment: Thanks, i will give a example, i want to make a select to all lines that some how are related to Dimobilli D2 for example, for the record 5 is easy, but i want the record 6 too, but the select on the where clause can not be the same, now mill must be the transdocnunber 5055, i think i must use a variable and use a loop, i must find the dimobilli d2 and then see the transdocnumber and use that instead the dimobilli d2

Comment: If you have changed expected output, please add sample output for us to workout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select rows with required text column and match corresponding Id's to get required output.

```
declare @table table (transdocnumber int, textanswer varchar(20))
insert @table (transdocnumber,textanswer)
select 4631, 'Dimibilli D4' union all
select 4631, '' union all
select 5055, 'Dimibilli D2' union all
select 5055, '' union all
select 5270, 'Dimibilli D2' union all 
select 5270, '' union all 
select 5270, '' union all 
select 5513, 'Dimibilli D2' union all 
select 6279, 'Dimibilli D4' union all 
select 6616, 'Dimibilli D2' union all 
select 6773, 'Dimibilli D4' 

select t.transdocnumber,t.textanswer from (
select transdocnumber from @table where textanswer = 'Dimibilli D2' ) x
inner join @table t on x.transdocnumber = t.transdocnumber where t.textanswer = ''
union all
select transdocnumber,textanswer from @table where textanswer = 'Dimibilli D2'
order by transdocnumber
```

Solution:

```
SELECT t.transdocnumber, t.extrafield_id, t.textanswer, t.BooleanAnswer, t.DtAlt
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE textanswer = 'Dimibilli D2'
    ) x
INNER JOIN TABLE t ON x.transdocnumber = t.transdocnumber
WHERE t.textanswer = ''

UNION ALL

SELECT transdocnumber, extrafield_id, textanswer, BooleanAnswer, DtAlt
FROM TABLE
WHERE textanswer = 'Dimibilli D2'
ORDER BY transdocnumber
```

Comment: But then the record number 4 will be select too, will not work

Comment: you right, what is the logic behind including only 6,8 and 9

Comment: was my mistake, there is a relationship between the column transdocnumber and textanswer, i want to see all transdocnumber that have on the textanswer the dimobbili d2

Comment: @AntónioSilva edited the answer to meet your required output

Comment: it works like a charm :-) Just add this "WHERE t.textanswer = 'Dimobilli D2' or t.textanswer = '' " and give me the correct output. Thanks very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.tansdocnumber in (select t2.transdocnumber from t t2 where t2.textanswer = 'Dimobili D2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table
where textanswer not in ('dimobilli d4')
```

Comment: will not work, you are only seeing 10 lines more or less , but is near 6000 records

Comment: Kindly add some sample test data and the logic as well

Answer (score 0):

for what I have understood you want to get back rows with textanswer='dimibilli d2' and textanswer='dimibilli d2' but not row 4.

You can't do that in this way, you should differentiate the row that you want in some way.

using

`select * from table
where (textanswer='dimibilli d2' or textanswer = '')`

as Ven suggested you will have line 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12 as result, but it seems that you want only 5,6,7,8,9,10,12

for example you can use:

`select * from table
where (textanswer='dimibilli d2' or textanswer = '') and TransDocNumber>5000;`

this should work

Comment: Op doesn't want to hard code in filter clause, he wants to use transdocnumber column, please refer to my edited solution above , it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below query:

```
select * from table
where (TextAnswer='Dimobili D2' or BooleanAnswer = '1') and TextAnswer!=''
```